# Cannot Delete File in try catch

Tags: java, file, try-catch, delete-file

I'll post my code first:

```
private void validateXml(String xml) throws BadSyntaxException{
    File xmlFile = new File(xml);
    try {
        JaxbCommon.unmarshalFile(xml, Gen.class);
    } catch (JAXBException jxe) {
        logger.error("JAXBException loading " + xml);
        String xmlPath = xmlFile.getAbsolutePath();
        System.out.println(xmlFile.delete()); // prints false, meaning cannot be deleted
        xmlFile.delete();
        throw new BadSyntaxException(xmlPath + "/package.xml");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException fne) {
        logger.error("FileNotFoundException loading " + xml + " not found");
        fne.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

You can see in my comment where I print that the file cannot be deleted.  Files can't be deleted from a `try`/`catch`?  So, if there is a file with bad xml syntax, I want to delete the file in the `catch`.

EDIT:  I can delete the file when I use `delete()` from outside of this function.  I am on Windows.

Comment: Which operating system are you using? Windows has the tendency to lock files, on Linux/Unix you might run into issues with permissions. Also, it can mean the file doesn't exist. Can you check using '.exists()'?

Comment: I am on Windows, currently.

Comment: Just curious, what's the catched `JAXBException` stack trace? Maybe it helps to determine if the file stills open and locked when you try to delete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that this method invocation `JaxbCommon.unmarshalFile(xml, Gen.class);` closes any stream when the exception occurs. If the stream that was reading the file is left opened then you cannot delete it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is unrelated to the try/catch.  Do you have permissions to delete the file?

If you are using Java 7 you can use the `Files.delete(Path)` which I think will actually throw an IOException with the reason why you can't delete the file.

Answer (score 0):

There is no general restriction regarding the use of `java.io.File.delete()` on try/catch blocks.

The behavior of many `java.io.File` methods can depend on platform/enviroment that the application is running. It is because they can need to access file system resources.

For example, the following code returns `false` on Windows 7 and `true` on Ubuntu 12.04:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {       
    File fileToBeDeleted = new File("test.txt");

    // just creates a simple file on the file system
    PrintWriter fout = new PrintWriter(fileToBeDeleted);

    fout.println("Hello");

    fout.close();

    // opens the created file and does not close it
    BufferedReader fin = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileToBeDeleted));

    fin.read();

    // try to delete the file
    System.out.println(fileToBeDeleted.delete());

    fin.close();
}
```

So, the real problem can depend on several factors. However, it is not related to the code residing on a try/catch block.

Maybe, the resource that you is trying to delete was opened and not closed or locked by another process.